# Function that allow me to create random email for cypress test

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, scripting, cypress

I'm looking into a function that allows me to create random emails where I would like to add it to the Email input inside of my test. For this reason, I created this function. However, I'm not sure how to add it to my cypress test.

Function:

```
 it('Product |  build or Remodel', () => {
    
    
    function string(){

    }
chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890';
    string = '';
    email = '@aharotest.com';
    
    for(var ii=0; ii<15; ii++){
        string += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
    }
    
    console.log(string + email)
    
    cy.oneTime()
    cy.buildRemodel()
    cy.get('#full_name')
    .type('MOCKA DATA TEST')
    cy.get('#company')
    .type('Bluehost')
    cy.get('#phone_number')
    .type('2022569879')
    cy.get('#email')
    cy.get('#password')
    .type('Abcd1234')
    cy.logOut()
  })
```

My element is `#email`

What could be the best way to approach this situation.

Comment: I think you could just use UUIDs for email usernames btw. Might make things easier.

Comment: I wish I can change the logic of my System, but I have to run a test like that....

Comment: I wasn't commenting on your need to test, so it has no bearing on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think most of the solutions here are needlessly complex.

This should be enough:

```js
cy.get('#input_email').type(`${Date.now()}@aharotest.com`)
```

No need for any 'helper' function
`${Date.now()}` will output the current unix time (e.g. `1674214877166`)

This will be different every time you run the test, so the email will always be unique.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this issue is to create a function that will create random text + adding a string that will complete the email.

My solution is:

```
 function makeid(length) {
        var result           = '';
        var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        var charactersLength = characters.length;
        for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
           result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
        }
        return result;
     }
     
     console.log(makeid(5));
```

My cypress command will be the following:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("form", ()=> {
      // fill-out form

      function makeid(length) {
        var result           = '';
        var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        var charactersLength = characters.length;
        for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
           result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
        }
        return result;
     }
     
     console.log(makeid(5));

    cy.get('#full_name')
      .type('MOCKDATA TESTING')
    cy.get('#company')
      .type('Testing')
    cy.get('#phone_number')
      .type('2022569878')
    cy.get('#email')
      .type(makeid(6) + "@aharo.com")
    cy.get('#password')
      .type('Abcd1234')

    // click submit
    cy.get(".app-submit-btn-text").click()
 })
```

The best way to call this command is `cy.form`.

Comment: I am using the above code to generate email ID to sign up registration and then want to use the same email address that generated for login. How can I do that using your solution?

Comment: Create a function to keep the record of the emails created and create an array where you will be able to grab those values later on.